# $S_n$ converging in $S$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, self-learning

We have a sequence  $\{X_n\}_{n\ge 1}$  given **(i)** $EX^2_n <\infty$ for all $n\ge 1$,also **(ii)**$E(X_m X_n)=0$ for all $ m\not =n$

and **(iii)** $\sum ^ \infty _ {n=1} EX^2_n <\infty$

I was trying to show that if $S_n=\sum ^ n _ {j=1} X_j$ for all $n\ge 1$ $$$$  Then $S_n$ converges in $L^2$ to some $S$ .
$$$$
( Even though I think that I probably have to show first that $S_n=\sum ^ n _ {j=1} X_j$ is Cauchy in  $L^2$  and after use the fact that $L^2$ is complete. I feel like I am missing something  ).

So I started like below.
 $sup_{m>n} E [ (S_m-S_n)^2] = sup_{m>n} E [ (\sum ^ m _ {j=n+1} X_j)^2]  =  sup_{m>n} E [ (\sum ^ m _ {j,k=n+1} X_j X_k)] = sup_{m>n}\sum ^ m _ {j,k=n+1} E[  X_j X_k ] = sup_{m>n}\sum ^ m _ {j=n+1} E[  X_j^2  ]= \sum ^ \infty _ {j=n+1} E[  X_j^2  ] \to0        $  as $n\to \infty$

Hence, $S_n $is Cauchy in $L^2$ .

If I have done everything correctly how do I finish the proof? is it enough to infer that $S_n$ converges in $L^2$ to some $S$   just from the completeness of $L^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct. The point is, that the condition $E[X_iX_j] = 0$ for all $i \neq j$ ensures the identity $E[\sum_{i \in I} (X_i^2)] = \sum_{i \in I} E[X_i^2]$ for any subset $I \subset \mathbb N$  because the cross terms vanish. Once this happens, then $(S_m -S_n)^2$ is dominated in expectation by $\sum_{n=1}^\infty E[X_i^2]$ which converges to zero since the entire sum is convergent.

Note that $X_iX_j$ being independent mean zero random variables with summable variance implies the starting conditions (which are weaker : the condition is called "uncorrelated"). Furthermore, it is also not difficult to show that $S_n$ in fact converge to the same random variable $S$ almost surely (follows from bounded variance of $S_n$ implying uniform integrability).